# How does hash-table in set works in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, set

As far as I know, `set` in python works via a hash-table to achieve `O(1)` look-up complexity. While it is hash-table, every entry in a `set` must be hashable (or immutable).
So This peace of code raises exception:

```py
>>> {dict()}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Because `dict` is not hashable. But we can create our own class inherited from `dict` and implement the `__hash__` magic method. I created my own in this way:

```py
>>> class D(dict):
...     def __hash__(self):
...             return 3
...
```

I know it should not work properly but I just wanted to experiment with it. So I checked that I can now use this type in `set`:

```py
>>> {D()}
{{}}
>>> {D(name='ali')}
{{'name': 'ali'}}
```

So far so good, but I thought that this way of implementing the `__hash__` magic method would screw up the look up in `set`. Because every object of the `D` has the same hash value.

```py
>>> d1 = D(n=1)
>>> d2 = D(n=2)
>>> hash(d1), hash(d2)
(3, 3)
>>> 
>>> {d1, d2}
{{'n': 2}, {'n': 1}}
```

But the surprise for me was this:

```py
>>> d3 = D()
>>> d3 in {d1, d2}
False
```

I expected the result to be `True`, because hash of `d3` is `3` and currently there are values in our set with the same hash value. How does the `set` works internally?

Comment: They hash to the same bucket, which will make your hash-lookups all collisions, **but they aren't equal, i.e. `__eq__`**, so they won't behave incorrectly. Of course, these are mutable objects, which will create *other problems* as well

Comment: The hash is only half the deal, the other halve is equality between the instances. And you have not implemented any equality.

Comment: Most algorithms that use hash table have to handle collisions — usually by storing a list of objects that have the same hash and doing a linear search checking for equality when one occurs.

Comment: "I expected the result to be True, because hash of d3 is 3 and currently there are values in our set with the same hash value. How does the set works internally?" Like a hash set / hash table. But you are making the mistake of thinking that a hash table decides whether something is or isn't in it by using *only* the hash value, it doesn't.

Comment: @luk2302 well, they inherit equality semantics from `dict`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be usable in sets and dicts, a `__hash__` method must guarantee that if `x == y`, then `hash(x) == hash(y)`. But that's a one-sided implication. It's not at all required that if `hash(x) == hash(h)` then `x == y` must be true. Indeed, that's impossible to achieve in general (for example, there are an unbounded number of distinct Python ints, but only a finite number of hash codes - there *must* be distinct ints that have the same hash value).

That your hashes are all the same is fine. They only tell the set/dict where to *start* looking. All objects in the container with the same hash are then compared, one by one, for equality, until success, or until all such objects have been tried without success.

However, while making all hashes the same doesn't hurt correctness, it's a disaster for performance: it effectively turns the set/dict into an exceptionally slow way to do an `O(n)` linear search.

Comment: It essentially turns it into a list where you do `if new_element not in the_set: the_set.append(new_element)`

Comment: @Barmar, it's worse than that. Same `O(n)` worst-case behavior, but at least a linear search through a list accesses memory in predictable order. The hash collision strategies for sets/dicts leap all over the container from one try to the next.