# return NotImplemented but when printed, I get False

Tags: python, class

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
class Attribut:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        other_name: str,
    ):
        self.name: str = name
        self.other_name: str = other_name
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Attribut):
            return self.name == other.name and self.other_name == other.other_name
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return 0
```

If I try to do:

```py
a = Attribut("lol", "a")
print(a==4)
```

I thought I would get `NotImplemented`, but instead I get `False`.

EDIT: (following chepner's answer)
Comparing one object from one class to an object to another class instead of comparing it to an integer:

```py
class Attribut:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        other_name: str,
    ):
        self.name: str = name
        self.other_name: str = other_name
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Attribut):
            return self.name == other.name and self.other_name == other.other_name
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

class Attribut2:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        other_name: str,
    ):
        self.name: str = name
        self.other_name: str = other_name
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Attribut2):
            return self.name == other.name and self.other_name == other.other_name
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

a = Attribut("lol", "a")
b = Attribut2("lol", "b")

print(a==b)
```

I also get `False`.

Also, what is the point of overriding `__hash__`, I cannot find a situation where this is useful?

Comment: One question per post, please. Asking about `NotImplemented` and `__hash__` is two unrelated questions.

Comment: I kinda screwed it now because I want to accept both answers that both answer my initial post. Oops ...

Answer (score 3):

When `a.__eq__(4)` returns `NotImplemented`, you don't get the value back immediately. Instead, Python attempts to call the reflected version of `__eq__` (`__eq__` itself) with the other argument, namely `(4).__eq__(a)`. It's this call that returns `False`.

By returning `NotImplemented`, you are not saying that `self` and `other` *cannot* be compared for equality (for that, raise a `ValueError`), but rather that `Attribut.__eq__` does not know how to do so, but perhaps the other argument's `__eq__` method does.

---

In your two-class example, we have the following:

1. `Attribut.__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`, so `Attribut2.__eq__` (since `self` and `other` have different types) is tried.
2. `Attribut2.__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`, so what gets tried next?

Since calling `Attribute.__eq__` again would just put us in an endless cycle, I *think* that Python falls back to `object.__eq__` instead (which can compare any two objects via object identity), but this is not obvious from the descriptions of either `NotImplemented` or `object.__eq__` itself. (This is supported by the fact that if you define both methods as

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return NotImplemented
```

and attempt to evaluate `a == a`, it evaluates to `True`.)

The closest thing to documentation for this that I can find is the following sentence from the description of [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> (The interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or some other fallback, depending on the operator.)

I suspect that whether or not `A.__eq__` is considered the reflection of `B.__eq__` depends on the context in which `B.__eq__` is called. That is, `A.__eq__` is *not* the reflection of `B.__eq__` in the case where `B.__eq__` was just called as the reflection of `A.__eq__`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this doesn't work when defining two classes Attribut and Attribut2 (cf. EDIT I made to the post for a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: I *think* what's happening is that Python keeps track of whether it has already tried the original, and is falling back to `object.__eq__` after both `Attribut.__eq__` and `Attribut2.__eq__` have returned `NotImplented`, to avoid an infinite cycle. I'll look for some documentation to that effect.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help!! I'm not sure I understand what you refer to when talking about `object.__eq__`. Who defined this method? Where is it?

Comment: It's defined in the Python implementation itself. Basically, it provides the default definition of `==` if neither operand provides any other definition of `__eq__`. It just falls back to object identity comparison, i.e., `a == b` if and only if `a is b`.

Comment: Oh, so if both the overrides of this return `NotImplemented`, then it comes back to the default definition of it?

Comment: I think so. I don't see any specific mention in the documentation how the cycle is broken, but that seems the most likely explanation. (Since there are only two classes involved, it's a short enough chain to easily break.)

Answer (score 2):

Overriding ****hash**** method allows you to use other methods that would involve sorting a list of your **Attribut** objects.

To test it create a script in which you would create such a list

```
a = [Attribut("lol", "a"),  Attribut("lol", "a"),  Attribut("lol", "a")]
```

and then try to make a set out of it

```
set(a)
```

If the method ****hash**** is implemented in **Attribut** class then there would be no problem. If not then the program will return an error **TypeError: unhashable type: 'Attribut'**

However, hash is only being used in Python hash-table and it's sole purpose is to make a number out of a class object.

Refer to these articles for more information:

- [How does hash-table in set works in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309235/how-does-hash-table-in-set-works-in-python)
- [What does "hashable" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python)

Also, there can be more than one object that would have the same hash - the comparison goes deeper and checks each fields of a class in methods that use comparison between two instances (like **set**). To make it possible there must be implemented the first step - main class must be hashable.

The hash should also be equal for the objects that should be equal. When comparison appears, Python first checks if two objects have the same hash, if not then the comparison results in **False**, no matter if two objects should be 'equal'.

You can try this code and check this behaviour. Comment/uncomment function body in **hash** function to be same or different hash:

```
from random import random

class Attribut:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        other_name: str,
    ):
        self.name: str = name
        self.other_name: str = other_name
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Attribut):
            return self.name == other.name and self.other_name == other.other_name
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        # Same hash
        # return 0
        # Different hash
        return hash(random())

c = [Attribut("lol", "a"), Attribut("lol", "a")]
print(set(c))
```

Comment: `NotImplemented` is intended to be returned, not raised.

Comment: `NotImplemented` is a singleton value, not to be confused with the exception class `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: @mlokos whatever what I put in `__hash__`, `set(a)` returns the same thing. Any idea why?

Comment: @mlokos `print(set([Attribut("lol", "a"), Attribut("lol", "b"), Attribut("lol", "c")]))` returns a `set` of length 3 even though all hashes are set to be the same: 0.

Comment: Yeah but if I always return the same thing, `set` should think they are doublons because have the same hash and should therefore remove them, right?

Comment: Changed the answer to better reflect what is being done under the scene. I have to admit that previously I wasn't aware of all of this and thought that set would be dependant solely on the **hash** method. Now it makes more sense. Please, refer to the two articles I've attached - there is a broader explanation of this

Comment: Ohhh, thank you for the reference, I didn't know any of that. All is clearer now!!